# Forcing a child form with CreateParam's Params.WndParent?

Tags: delphi

In some legacy D7 code I inherited and am migrating to XE5, I found the code below.

The comment states it's tricking windows into thinking it's a child form if it's created from a non-WinControl. There is one place in the code base where Create is called with AOwner as nil. (A form *is* available at the time of that call, so not sure why they did that...)

Any suggestions as to what the programmer's goal was?

```
private
  FParentWinControl: TWinControl; {Don't mess with! Used in CreateParams}
  procedure TFormX.CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams); override;
public
  constructor TFormX.Create( AOwner: TComponent); reintroduce;
end;

constructor TFormX.Create( AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  if AOwner IS TWinControl then
    FParentWinControl := TWinControl(AOwner)
  else
    FParentWinControl := NIL;
  inherited Create(AOwner);
end; { Create }


procedure TFormX.CreateParams(var params: TCreateParams);
begin
  inherited CreateParams(params);
  if (NOT fCreateParamsHasBeenRun) then
    begin
      fCreateParamsHasBeenRun := TRUE;
      if Assigned(FParentWinControl) then
        Params.WndParent := FParentWinControl.Handle; {tricks windows into thinking it's a child form}
    end;
end;
```

Comment: `Params.WndParent` is `hWndParent` to `CreateWindowEx`, see MSDN docs for full explanation. Unless 'TFormX' has `WS_CHILD` specified in styles (which doesn't seem to be the case), the window is created as owned by the owner (AOwner), it's not a child. I have no idea what the programmer has thought. It is very likely, although, that he didn't exactly know what he was doing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This code predates and loosely mimics the [`PopupMode` and `PopupParent`](http://blogs.embarcadero.com/abauer/2004/02/10/295) properties that were added to `TCustomForm` in Delphi 8.  Assuming `AOwner` is another Form, use those properties in modern Delphi versions, eg:

```
constructor TFormX.Create( AOwner: TComponent);
begin
  inherited Create(AOwner);
  if AOwner Is TCustomForm then
    PopupParent := TCustomForm(AOwner);
end;
```

Also, the use of `fCreateParamsHasBeenRun` was wrong. `CreateParams()` is called every time the Form's window is (re)created, so the `WndParent` needed to be applied every time, not conditionally.  If you need to keep the `CreateParams()` logic (such as if `AOwner` is a non-`TCustomForm` windowed control), you need to remove `fCreateParamsHasBeenRun`.

Comment: Good spot Remy!  It may be worth explaining the effect the code has (owned  form "stays on top" of the owner form) and the fact that the use of the term "child" in the comment in the original code refers to the parenting relationship involved in z-order and not to any "containment" relationship (which was what sent me off on my own particular wild goose chase!).

Comment: Thanks to both of you. Deltics: yes, stay on top is what the user was trying to do.